# ReactJS issue when doing component recursion "Uncaught TypeError: nodes1 is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem when referencing the component itself to build a group of components from a list. How can I make such recursion in a component? From where I got "nodes1" call?

NotesGroup.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Note from "./Note";

const NotesGroup = ({ notes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {notes.map(({ id, note, nodes }) => {
        return <Note key={id} id={id} note={note} nodes={nodes} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotesGroup;
```

Note.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Note = ({ id, note, nodes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="note">
      <span className="note__id">{id}</span>
      <span className="note__note">{note}</span>
      nodes ?{" "}
      {nodes.map(({ id, note, nodes }) => {
        return <Note key={id} id={id} note={note} nodes={nodes} />;
      })}
      : null
    </div>
  );
};

export default Note;
```

sample `notes` object (passed to `NotesGroup` component)

```js
const notes = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      note: "This is a note",
      nodes: [
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          note: "This is a note 2",
          nodes: [
            {
              id: uuidv4(),
              note: "This is a note 3",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          note: "This is a note 4",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      note: "This is a note 5",
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You map is set up wrong. You can only pass in two params e.g value (the key of the array) index (the number of the array being rendered)

So change the following

```
const NotesGroup = ({ notes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {notes.map(({ id, note, nodes }) => {
        return <Note key={id} id={id} note={note} nodes={nodes} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

to this

```
const NotesGroup = ({ notes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {notes.map((value, index) => {
        return <Note key={index} id={value.id} note={value.note} nodes={value.nodes} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

then in Note.js you are trying to map the component that is the component itself? Assuming thats a typo you do a similar thing

change

```
const Note = ({ id, note, nodes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="note">
      <span className="note__id">{id}</span>
      <span className="note__note">{note}</span>
      nodes ?{" "}
      {nodes.map(({ id, note, nodes }) => {
        return <Note key={id} id={id} note={note} nodes={nodes} />;
      })}
      : null
    </div>
  );
};
```

to this

```
const Note = ({ id, note, nodes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="note">
      <span className="note__id">{id}</span>
      <span className="note__note">{note}</span>
      nodes ?{" "}
      {nodes.map((value, index) => {
        return <Note key={index} id={value.id} note={value.note} />; //CHECK THIS
      })}
      : null
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I mean but I pass there one object in the map - just using destructuring, `nodes.map(({ id, note, nodes })` is equal to `nodes.map((value)`